# Android instumentation tests fail because of RenderScript

Tags: java, android, gradle, renderscript, android-espresso

I am building some ui tests with Espresso and everything works fine until I access a view in the application where RenderScript is used to blur an image.

The test fails with the error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved
>   to unexpected implementation

From what I googled it seems this happens because there are 2 instances of the same class in the test application, and the majority of solutions hint that the problem may be the `guava` library added twice. But this is not my case, as it fails very clearly on a line of code where RenderScript is instantiated.

Have you experienced something similar? I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I used a little hack to fix this problem.

The hack is to have a flag class (can be empty) in `androidTest->java->com` (location is not particular but is important to be part of `androidTest`).

Something like this:

```
public class TestsRunningFlag {
}
```

Then have an utility method that checks if that class can be loaded.

```
    /**
     * A hacky way to determine whether the application is running normally,
     * or as part of an instrumentation test.
     */
    public static boolean isTestMode(Context context) {
        boolean result;
        try {
            context.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.TestsRunningFlag");
            result = true;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And then based on whether I am in test mode or not, I use RenderScript to process the image or not.